# How to divide in sections in four quadrants + make clicks in collapsable listbox independent of clicks in section

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**Description/Approach**

I'm trying to merge the two pens:

https://codepen.io/ramsaylanier/pen/xcdiq?q=section&limit=all&type=type-pens

and

https://codepen.io/jasonpaul/pen/NxjvjW?q=collapse&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false

Ideally, I would like to make the four sections appear in a quadrant-like form (two sections in the first row and two sections in the bottom row). Each section should have a collapsable listbox. When the user clicks on the listbox the section shouldn't expand as well. Clicks in the listbox and in the section should be independent.

Regarding the clicks I think I have to tell the `toggleClass` to ignore clicks on `.collapsible`. Not sure how.

```
    $('.section').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
})

  $(".collapsible").collapsible({accordion: true});
  $(".collapsible").collapsible({accordion: false});
```

**Code**

https://codepen.io/szeconku/pen/oqBPvO

I need to figure out how to make clicks in the listbox independent of the clicks in the section and how to add a second row. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mxRgwV

Comment: Nice. Thx. I noticed you added `top:350px;` to the two sections in the bottom row. They are overlapping. Is there a way to prevent this? I could set it to 400px or so but I was wondering if it was possible to make it more dynamic like top: full height/2. Also when I expand one section it only expands to one row. I doesn't expand to the entire screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Codepen updated** : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oqBrbq

```js
$('.section').on('click', function(e){
  $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
})


  $(".collapsible").collapsible({accordion: true});
  $(".collapsible").click(function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

```css
.section {
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  height: calc( 50% - 2px);
  width: 50vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*@include skew(-10deg, 0deg);*/
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.section::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
  background-color: #3498DB;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  transition: all 500ms ease-out;
}
.section::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -15%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 130%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.3;
  z-index: -1;
  -moz-transform: skew(10deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(10deg, 0deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(10deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(10deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.section:hover {
  width: 47%;
  z-index: 30;
}
.section:hover::after {
  background-size: 50%;
}
.section:hover:last-of-type {
  left: 53%;
}
.section.expanded {
  width: 100% !important;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, 0deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, 0deg);
}
.section.expanded::after {
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, 0deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, 0deg);
  background-size: 50%;
  background-position: left;
}
.section.expanded:hover:last-of-type {
  left: 0px;
}
.section.expanded:hover::after {
  background-size: 50%;
  background-position: left;
}

.section-1 {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.section-1::before {
  background-color: #1DB45D;
}

.section-2 {
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
}
.section-2::before {
  background-color: #3498DB;
}

.section-3 {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.section-3::before {
  background-color: #9B59B6;
}

.section-4 {
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
}
.section-4::before {
  background-color: #F06D3A;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <section class="section-1 section">
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="expandable">
        <li>
          <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="mdi-navigation-chevron-right"></i>Bullet 1</div>
          <div class="collapsible-body">
            <p>Bullet 1 text</div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="section-2 section">
    <h1>Title 2</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="section-3 section">
    <h1>Title 3</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="section-4 section">
    <h1>Title 4</h1>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx. When I add more text or more bullets they disappear from a section. I tried to add something like `overflow-y:auto;` in the CSS which works somewhat. I just need to restrict the scrollable view to the section.